# Grant ubuntu access to www-data

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions

I'm running Ubuntu and would like to be able to upload files using SSH to update the website code.

**my ubuntu user ( id ubuntu )**

```
root@****:/var/www# id ubuntu
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu)     groups=1000(ubuntu),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),33(www-data),44(video),46(plugdev),102(netdev)
```

**My ubuntu groups (groups ubuntu)**

```
root@****:/var/www# groups ubuntu
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip www-data video plugdev netdev
```

**All the groups on my ubuntu server (more /etc/group)**

```
    root@****:/var/www# more /etc/group
    root:x:0:
    daemon:x:1:
    bin:x:2:
    sys:x:3:
    adm:x:4:syslog,ubuntu
    tty:x:5:
    disk:x:6:
    lp:x:7:
    mail:x:8:
    news:x:9:
    uucp:x:10:
    man:x:12:
    proxy:x:13:
    kmem:x:15:
    dialout:x:20:ubuntu
    fax:x:21:
    voice:x:22:
    cdrom:x:24:ubuntu
    floppy:x:25:ubuntu
    tape:x:26:
    sudo:x:27:ubuntu
    audio:x:29:ubuntu
    dip:x:30:ubuntu
    www-data:x:33:ubuntu
    backup:x:34:
    operator:x:37:
    list:x:38:
    irc:x:39:
    src:x:40:
    gnats:x:41:
    shadow:x:42:
    utmp:x:43:
    video:x:44:ubuntu
    sasl:x:45:
    plugdev:x:46:ubuntu
    staff:x:50:
    games:x:60:
    users:x:100:
    nogroup:x:65534:
    libuuid:x:101:
    netdev:x:102:ubuntu
    crontab:x:103:
    syslog:x:104:
    fuse:x:105:
    messagebus:x:106:
    mlocate:x:107:
    ssh:x:108:
    landscape:x:109:
    admin:x:110:
    ubuntu:x:1000:
    mysql:x:111:
    ssl-cert:x:112:
```

Why am i unable to overwrite files in the /www/var/html folder as Ubuntu user?

**EDIT**

**My Folder permissions for /var/www and /var/www/html are:**

```
root@****:/var/www# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 20:24 html
root@****:/var/www# cd html
root@****:/var/www/html# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 9 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 20:24 somefolder
```

**MOUNTED DRIVES (mount)**

```
    root@****:/# mount
    /dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,discard)
    proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
    sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
    none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
    none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
    none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
    none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
    udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
    devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
    tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
    none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
    none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
    none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
    none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
    /dev/xvdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw)
    systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Comment: What permissions do /www, /www/var, and /www/var/html have? And are they local disks or mounted?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 20:22 www **AND** drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 20:24 html ... EBS mounted drive on AWS

Comment: Mounted: how, what does `mount` say about the mount options of that disk?

Comment: I added the "mount" details to the question. any ideas why i'm having such a hard time for something so simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Why am i unable to **overwrite** files in the /var/www/html folder as Ubuntu user?"

My understanding is that you are able to *write* files inside */var/www/html* but you are unable to *overwrite* files written by other `www-data` group users (If you cannot overwrite the files/directories `owned` by you, that's a completely different problem).

You are allowed to write files inside `/var/www/html` for these reasons:

- */var/www/html* is owned by `www-data` user and is in the group `www-data`
- You are a user of the `www-data group`
- */var/www/html* has write permissions for the group

By default, when you create a file/directory inside */var/www/html*, you are the owner of the file and the group of the file is set to your `primary` group (`ubuntu` in your case).
Others outside your primary group have no `write` permissions.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 123 Oct 12 13:14 test.html
```

This policy is the same for all the users of www-data group and creates a problem of not allowing you to overwrite a file created by other members of www-data (unless they  manually change the file group to www-data).

A solution to this problem, is to force every file/directory created inside */var/www/html* to have `www-data` as the group. This is done using [setgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html
```

**Make sure all the group users have write permissions for all the files/directories:**

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

**Setgid for already existing directories inside /var/www/html**

```
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```